# The for loop does not work properly under while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program which take statement from the user and then  apply question mark and full stop into the sentence and combine it to form a paragraph.
Here is the some code I have written till now

```
Enter : Ray
Enter : What was that
Enter : \end
['Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Hi my name .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'Ray .', 'What was that ?', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', 'What was that .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .', '\\end .']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
que = ('What', 'Where', 'Who', 'Which', 'Why', 'When', 'How', 'Whose', 'Am', 'Will', 'Is')
a = []
while True:
    statement = input("Enter : ")
    statement_list = statement.split()
    for i in que:
        if (i==statement_list[0]):
            a.append(statement + ' ?')
        else:
            a.append(statement + ' .')
    if statement == '\end':
        break

print(a)
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? Wrong output? Please provide some details. Read about [ask] and provide a [mre]

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Instead of the `for` loop why not just do `if statement_list[0] in que`?

Comment: Each turn through `for i in que` you append something to `a`. So `a` will contain the same statement 11 times. I guess that's not what you want...?

Comment: What error? There is no error. Think about your logic. You pass through all question words and then either add an element with `?` or `.` in the end. What if the sentence really starts with `What`? Then when the `for` loop will reach What it will add it with a `?` but then for all others it will add with a `.`. If you think about it you don't really need a `for` loop here. You just want to check `if statement_list[0] in que`...

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this.

```
que = ('What', 'Where', 'Who', 'Which', 'Why', 'When', 'How', 'Whose', 'Am', 'Will', 'Is')
a = []
while True:
    statement = input("Enter : ")
    if statement == '\end':
        break
    statement_list = statement.split()
    if statement_list[0] in que:
        a.append(statement + '?')
    else:
        a.append(statement + '.')

print(a)
```

What I'm doing differently here is, I'm checking if the first word the user entered is in  `que`. If that is so, we now know for sure, we can put a `?` at the end. Say the first word the user entered was not in `que`, we would end the statement with a `.`
Also, you were checking if the user entered `\end` after you append the statement to `a`. Instead, before appending `\end` to your list, you check if the user entered `\end`, that way `\end` wont be in your list.